# How to make particles change their direction 90 degrees

Tags: particles

I am trying to replicate this particle effect in blender - https://vimeo.com/219576444 I especially want the particles to change their direction 90 degrees, like in the video.

Particularly this part

[image]

How can I do this in a blender?

Comment: To clarify the effect seen if pausing vid at 1 second mark? If so could you please add a screenshot.

Comment: @batFINGER I'm interested in this part https://i.imgur.com/r8jgPnf.png

Comment: Please [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/195407/edit) any extra details into question. Have a search  for  questions re lightning.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not an actual particle system

It's more like a mesh that being exposed ***presumably*** by some empty object or something like that:
[image]
[image]

Though I'm not sure how it's actually done, and as soon as I know there's no way to make particles do that straight kind of motion

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different approach.  And I suspect this is what he did the more I look at it.

1. Animate a single object yourself that moves in the pattern that you want. Duplicate that object a few times and offset the animations from one another.
2. Offset the rotations in 90 degree increments between them around the emitter axis.
3. Group this entire collection.
4. Make a particle emmiter that emits this group.
5. Play with the particle system rotation and randomness settings from here to fine tune.

If you want to get fancier, you can animate the turns procedurally on the object so it randomizes the turns.  Additionally, the object you are animating can be a particle system to get more control over the trails that you might want.

This is based partially on the suggestions of Richard Marklew on Blender artists. https://blenderartists.org/t/offset-particle-object-animation/489919/3